# Algorithm to output a subset of set A such that it maximizes the overall pairwise sum

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose I have a set `A={a_1, a_2, ..., a_n}`. I also have a function `f:AxA->R` that assigns a pair from `A` a certain real value. I want to extract a subset `S_k` of size `k`  from `A` such that it maximizes the overall pairwise sum of all elements  in `S_k`

Is there any known algorithm that would do this in **reasonable** time? polynomial/quasi-polynomial time perhaps?

**Edit: Worked Example**

Suppose `A={a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4}` with `k=3` and `f` is defined as:

`f(a_1,a_2)=0`,`f(a_1,a_3)=0`,`f(a_1,a_4)=0`,`f(a_2,a_3)=1`,`f(a_2,a_4)=5`,`f(a_3,a_4)=10`.

Then `S_k={a_2,a_3,a_4}` since it maximizes the sum `f(a_2,a_3)+f(a_2,a_4)+f(a_3,a_4)`. (i.e. the pairwise sum of all elements in S_k)

Comment: Uhm, so is `f(x, y) = x + y`, or something else? Please post a worked example.

Comment: "such that it maximizes the overall pairwise sum of all elements in S_k".. what does it means ? Can You give example ?

Comment: @IVlad Added a working example

Comment: @MateuszW90 The sum of all pairs of entered in the function. See the example

Comment: What complexity are you looking for? Is `O(n^2 log n)` acceptable?

Comment: `n` ranges to a `1000` so `O(n^2 log n)` should be pretty good.

Comment: Is this from a programming competition? If so, could you give the source to the original problem?

Comment: @RazimanT.V. It is not. It is a problem that I am facing in my research work and I am quiet stuck at.

Comment: I just wanted to know if f(ai, aj) had some nice property we could exploit. Is f completely random, or does it derive from something else?

Comment: @RazimanT.V. It is random really. You can think of it as a 2D symetric matrix that has random numbers in it with row i and column j representing f(a_i,a_j)

Answer (score 6):

Unlikely -- this problem generalizes the problem of finding a k-clique (set the weights to the adjacency matrix of the graph), for which the best known algorithms are exponential (see also the strong exponential time hypothesis).

Comment: Hmm, I see. Do you happen to know if there are any good approximation algorithms? Also, by k-clique problem, you mean the problem of testing whether a graph G contains a k-vertex clique?

Comment: @user3508551 I'm not sure what people do in practice. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_subgraph) points to a ratio n^(1/4+eps)-factor approximation, which seems unlikely to be practical.

Comment: To see how k-clique reduces to this problem: For a given graph G = (V, E) your set will be the vertices V, and the function f(i, j) will be 1 if (i,j) is an edge in E and 0 otherwise. You can then convince yourself that a clique will achieve the maximum possible sum of k * (k-1) /2. So if your algorithm would run in polynomial time, you could decide in polynomial time whether or not a graph has a k-clique.